# Gcc 3.2.3 "no matching function for call to" error with template function

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

**Declaration in .h file, as part of Item class:**

```
template<typename TCastTarget>    inline TCastTarget* as() const
{
  ...
  return const_cast<TCastTarget *>(static_cast<const TCastTarget *>(atomicValue));
}
```

Code in .cpp:

```
Numeric* l_ptmp = next.as<Numeric>(); //next is of type Item
```

Error message:

> functions/qcomparingaggregator.cpp:129: no matching function for call to 'QPatternist::Item::as()'

Any idea what's the problem with this code? Item class isn't templated, only its `as()` function is.
If this matters, code is part of Qt module.

Notice the old gcc version that's being used (3.2.3), as newer versions compiled this code OK. Needless to say I cannot use the newer Gcc.. :(

Comment: Is the code where you're attempting to call `as()` inside of a template?

Comment: I think what he is not showing us is that he is subclassing Qt's `QPatternist::Item` and possibly has overloaded `as()` incorrectly. Apart from that casting away constness is usually bad and this template wrapper design could be improved if more information was given about the actual problem ...